# String replace using sed in tcl script - string contains round brackets

Tags: regex, string, sed, tcl, substitution

I want to use sed in a tcl script to modify a file (stored in $file) that contains the string:

> prbs_match_out <= (ch0_prbs_match_dual3_int  & 
>   ch0_prbs_match_dual2_int  &  ch0_prbs_match_dual1_int  & 
>   ch0_prbs_match_int) & (   ch1_prbs_match_dual3_int  & 
>   ch1_prbs_match_dual2_int  &  ch1_prbs_match_dual1_int  & 
>   ch1_prbs_match_int);

to

> prbs_match_out <= ch0_prbs_match_int  &  ch1_prbs_match_int;

Attempt:

```
exec /bin/sed -i {s/(ch0_prbs_match_dual3_int  &  ch0_prbs_match_dual2_int  &  ch0_prbs_match_dual1_int  &  ch0_prbs_match_int) & (   ch1_prbs_match_dual3_int  &  ch1_prbs_match_dual2_int  &  ch1_prbs_match_dual1_int  &  ch1_prbs_match_int)/ch0_prbs_match_int & ch1_prbs_match_int/g}  $file
```

The above sed command does not work (get an incorrect substitution). How do I handle round brackets and ampersands in sed?

Comment: can you simplfy your problem to "replace any line beginning like `prbs_match_out <=` with `prbs_match_out <= ch0_prbs_match_int & ch1_prbs_match_int;`, or is the large line you have included really the only version of `prbs_match_out <=` that you need to fix? Also, read thru http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html. Good luck.

Comment: I want to only fix the line (unique)

`prbs_match_out <= (ch0_prbs_match_dual3_int & ch0_prbs_match_dual2_int & ch0_prbs_match_dual1_int & ch0_prbs_match_int) & ( ch1_prbs_match_dual3_int & ch1_prbs_match_dual2_int & ch1_prbs_match_dual1_int & ch1_prbs_match_int);`

Comment: Also note that `sed` cannot easily match patterns that stretch across multiple lines of text. It's unclear in your sample data if that is one continuous line of text or formatted across multiple lines. You'll need to escape parens and `&` chars, as they have special meaning for `sed` regexs. So (maybe) `s/\(ch0_prbs_match_dual3_int  \& ....\)` ... Depending on the version of sed you're using and any options you have included you may not need to escape the parens. Best to get a small sample working first, then try it on your full line. Good luck.

Comment: In sed's BRE, parentheses and ampersand have no special meaning. `&` *does* have special meaning in the *replacement* part of the `s` command. If you run sed with `sed -r` or `sed -E`, then you're using ERE and parentheses become special in the pattern.

Comment: @LokSas, the formatting of your question make it difficult to reproduce. Does your input contain newlines? Are multiple spaces significant or not?

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider using Tcl for this in-place transformation, e.g. via its [`[regsub]`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm) command:

```
set x [regsub {(\([^)]*\))} $x ch0_prbs_match_int]
set x [regsub {(\([^)]*\))} $x ch1_prbs_match_int]
```

> only fix the line (unique)

This assumes that variable `x` holds the content of your file and that the line elements to be replaced can be uniquely identified by watching out for the matching pairs of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the file **contents** (or a line of the file) in a variable, you can use the [`string map`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm) command to replace one substring with some other text.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - tcl's "string map" command worked. Thanks for your help.

```
package require Tcl 8.5

package require fileutil

# Parameters for the replacement 
set from "(   ch0_prbs_match_dual3_int  &  ch0_prbs_match_dual2_int  &  ch0_prbs_match_dual1_int  &  ch0_prbs_match_int) & (   ch1_prbs_match_dual3_int  &  ch1_prbs_match_dual2_int  &  ch1_prbs_match_dual1_int  &  ch1_prbs_match_int)"
set to "ch0_prbs_match_int & ch1_prbs_match_int"

# Which file to replace 
set checkingFile /proj/dada/test.v

# Make a command fragment that performs the replacement on a supplied string
set replacementCmd [list string map [list $from $to]]

# For single file replacement 
fileutil::updateInPlace $checkingFile $replacementCmd
```

Answer (score 0):

In a `BRE` (basic regular expression), only six characters must be escaped
to be literally handled: `^$.*\[`.
In addition, you need to escape
`&` in the `REPLACEMENT` part of the `s` command in `sed`, because `&`
has a special meaning of the matched portion in the `PATTERN`.
As a result, you can say something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set file {yourfilename}
exec /bin/sed -i {s/(ch0_prbs_match_dual3_int & ch0_prbs_match_dual2_int & ch0_prbs_match_dual1_int & ch0_prbs_match_int) & ( ch1_prbs_match_dual3_int & ch1_prbs_match_dual2_int & ch1_prbs_match_dual1_int & ch1_prbs_match_int);/ch0_prbs_match_int \& ch1_prbs_match_int;/} $file
```

which modifies the `$file` as:

```
prbs_match_out <= ch0_prbs_match_int & ch1_prbs_match_int;
```

Comment: You can't say exactly that… because that's the classic single-quotes-when-calling-shell-command issue (note the tag `tcl`). I've answered it recently so I don't want to answer it again for a while…

Comment: I do appreciate your advice. I'll keep it in my mind :-).

Comment: @DonalFellows It turns out the `sed` command works just by modifying the quotes from single quotes to curly braces so it can be executed from within `tcl`.

Comment: Thanks for your response and explanation but that didn't work :(

Comment: @LokSas Would you please be specific about how it does *not* work (e.g. output, error
message, etc.) including your `sed` and `tcl` version?
I've tested with sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 and tclsh 8.6. 
If you have solved the issue with others' answers, you do not have to
spend your time to answer this comment anyway. BR.